# how to open a jar file in ubuntu for hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cloud

hey hi I have written code and i tried running the jar but i got an exception saying that jar file cannot be opened and i even changed the file permissions and path is also set right but it is still showing me error saying that jar file cannot be opened.
Please suggest some solutions.

[image]

that is the error i got and even i have gone through the wordcount example also but could not get any answer.

Comment: Show the code have written.

Comment: are you asking me the java code?

Answer (score 0):

Is your jar file in local file system or hdfs? The jar file should be in local file system.

Comment: hey hi it is in the localsystem only but still it is showing me that error i placed it in jar file